# TSQL throw weird error when commenting a line of text

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Here is a strange situation. Following code works perfectly if I run it as is, but if I comment the first CHARINDEX line, it throws an error.

> Msg 536, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
> Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

```
SELECT 
DT.DataID
,RIGHT(K.IniValue, LEN( K.IniValue ) - 15)
--error if you comment the next line
 ,CHARINDEX('}',SUBSTRING(K.IniValue,CHARINDEX('ExtShared',K.IniValue) + 12,LEN(K.IniValue))) AS LastPosition
  ,REPLACE( CONCAT( REPLACE( RIGHT(K.IniValue, LEN( K.IniValue ) - 15), '''}', '' ), SUBSTRING( P.providerData, CHARINDEX( '''providerInfo''=''', P.providerData ) + 16, CHARINDEX( ''',''storage', P.providerData ) - ( CHARINDEX( '''providerInfo''=''', P.providerData ) + 16 ))), '\\', '\' )

FROM llprod.DTreeCore AS DT
INNER JOIN llprod.DVersData AS DV ON DV.DocID = DT.DataID AND DT.VersionNum = DV.Version
INNER JOIN llprod.ProviderData AS P ON DV.ProviderId = P.providerID
INNER JOIN llprod.KIni AS K ON K.IniKeyword = P.providerType
--WHERE ( k.IniValue LIKE '%{%' and K.IniValue LIKE '%}%' AND k.IniValue LIKE '%ExtShared%')
WHERE DT.DataiD = 123456
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: We cannot reproduce the error without the DDL for the tables. Please, add them so that we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

I forget what the term is for this or how to articulate it properly (my apologies) but I've experienced something similar before where the function you're applying in the `SELECT` list is being analyzed over your data before the `WHERE` clause actually filters down the data.

You likely have a value for the `K.IniValue` field in the `llprod.KIni` entity that has a length less than 15 characters, which would result in an invalid index (a negative number) for the `RIGHT()` function. When you comment out the first `CHARINDEX()` field, a different **execution plan** is being generated that results in the above scenario I just mentioned, and therefore the `RIGHT()` function is breaking (even though your `WHERE` clause may actually filter out all cases that should cause it to break, because the `RIGHT()` function is being analyzed over the data first).

To fix this, you can put a `CASE` statement checking the `LENGTH()` of `K.IniValue` before applying the `RIGHT()` function, so you can direct the **execution plan** appropriately by explicitly telling it how to handle cases when the `K.InitValue` has a `LENGTH()` less than 15 characters, in a non-breaking manner.

Comment: I think i found a value which doesn't contain any of the expressions mentioned on the CHARINDEX()  statement. But those records wont be returned for those particular DataID. The part I dont understand is Why it is throwing an error when I comment the CHARINDEX line. Somehow SQL server is considering the value of that expression when it is not commented.

Comment: The issue isn't *particularly* related to your `CHARINDEX()` function rather commenting and uncommenting it just coincendentally results in a different **execution plan**. The issue is your data in the `K.InitValue` has a value for some row where the length is less than 15 characters. I bet if you ran a `SELECT * FROM llprod.KIni WHERE LEN(InitValue) < 15` it'll return rows. If you add a `CASE` statement to your `RIGHT()` function call as my answer mentions, then your issue will go away. Again, it doesn't matter your predicates filter out those records from `llprod.KIni` that would break it...

Comment: ...the `RIGHT()` function is being analyzed against the data before it's being filtered in the other **execution plan**.

Comment: @Nish I just realized I forgot to tag you. Please see my previous comments.

Comment: @JD, Thanks, you are right RIGHT() function is validated first. I compared the estimated execution plan. Above query does a  TableScan -->Sort>Compute Scalar  operation on KIni table. While with that column commented out, it performs TableScan ->ComputeScalar ->Sort . I guess the ComputeScalar operation is throwing the error. Its so weird seeing RIGHT() operation performing before WHERE clause

Comment: @Nish Indeed, it's unintuitive, and kind of goes against the *order of events* but there's no guarantee in the way SQL Server will execute the query and so once in a while a weird issue like this pops up. I've had it happen before myself.

Comment: Good catch, J.D.  I've linked this Q&A to several duplicates on the site.

Comment: @JoshDarnell Thanks for the link! I'll read up on it so next time I can articulate the name of this behavior better lol.